# required-поля в rest-api через spring mvc

Tags: spring, mvc, required

Spring mvc. В контроллере метод аргумента принимает

```
@RequestBody RequestDto requestDto
```

Сам класс имеет следующий вид:

```
@Data
public class RequestDto {
    private List<String> users;
    private String comment;
    private Integer age;
}
```

Нужно, чтобы при запросе на мой контроллер клиент отправлял в json-сообщении все три поля. Но сейчас, если клиент отправит только users и age, а comment пропустит, то контроллер воспримет такой запрос, просто поле comment поставит как =null. А меня это не устраивает, нужно чтобы значения всех трех полей явно указывались в запросе, пусть даже это будет null-значения.

`@NotNull` не подходит, потому что null может быть.

`@NotEmpty` не подходит, потому что он примерим только к коллекциям и массивам.

`@NotBlank` не подходит, потому что может быть как null, так и пустая строка.

Нужно что-то вроде `@Required`

Comment: ну так укажите сразу 2 аннотации `@NotNull @NotBlank private String comment;` , как в этом [примере](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21172774/6752984) , и если есть ошибка в этом поле, то пользователю отдавать "комментарий - обязательное поле"

Comment: @MrFylypenko not null не подойдет, потому что значение может быть null. главное условие - чтобы клиент явно это указал в запросе. Так же и not blank - значение может быть blank, главное чтобы клиент явно об этом сказал

Comment: Тогда посмотрите этот [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47807039/6752984) , вроде работает, но придется больше кода писать. Либо напишите свой обработчик аннотации `@Required` , который будет это делать.